# Как в комбобоксе программно установить курсор в конец строки?

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, как в комбобоксе программно установить курсор в конец строки? Можно ли это сделать?

Comment: Конкретизируйте задачу не совсем ясно что и зачем вы хотите сделать.

Comment: Пользователь вводит для поиска в строке комбобокса буквы. После каждой введенной буквы список строк комбобокса меняется в зависимости от введенных букв. Проблема в том, что каждый раз после пересчета комбобокса указатель встает на первую букву и пользователю приходится вручную перемещать его в конец. Хотелось бы этого избежать.

Comment: По-моему вы изобретаете велосипед.  
При вводе символов в текст комбобокса, комбобокс сам подставляет в текст наиболее похожее значение из тех, что есть в его объектах.  Если в вашем CBox'e слишком много строк, то лучше разделить их на подгруппы, и поставить рядом еще один CBox, в котором вы выбираете группу, и устанавливаете отбор строк во втором CBox'e.

Comment: У меня не все так просто: при выборе значения в комбобоксе пересчитывается DBGrid. Пользователь может выбрать (или вводить символы), потом передумать и попробовать другой вариант. Если он вводил буквы, то может захотеть выбрать из списка и там должны быть только актуальные значения. Поэтому я и пересчитываю комбобокс всякий раз после выбора или ввода символов.

Comment: 1. Все же советую сделать нормальную структуру данных   
2. Вам ничего не мешает делать отбор по группам, используя  вложенности CBox (select ... where (group1 = a) and (group2 = b) ... (groupN = N))  
3. Когда пользователь с помощью CBox выбирает нужную ему группу данных, даете ему возможность уточнить запись с помощью введения символов в TEdit (select ... where (group1 = a) and (group2 = b) ... (groupN = N) and (param = myTEditText))
4. Если пользователь решит передумать, просто убираете отмененное им условие из запроса.  
Для этого всего вам нужно будет сделать красивый конструктор запросо

Comment: Спасибо за советы, но у меня нет такой проблемы, что "Если в вашем CBox'e слишком много строк". Проблема, что курсор соскакивает на начало. Попробовал SelStart, но так некрасиво - курсор скачет туда-сюда.

Comment: ComboBox1.ItemIndex := ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1;

Comment: @perchuk, не последний элемент, а последний символ в строке

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Лучше не сделать:

```
procedure Combobox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Combobox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  Combobox1.Items.Clear;
  Combobox1.SelStart:=Length(Combobox1.Text);
  Combobox1.AddStrings(SomeStrings);
  Combobox1.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
```

Comment: Yura Ivanov, спасибо, так работает. Собственно, достаточно ставить SelStart сразу после Clear.

Comment: BeginUpdate и EndUpdate нужны чтоб не было мигания при открытом комбобоксе. А так да, проблему решает selstart.

Comment: Спасибо, понятно.

Answer (score 2):

Вот решение под стать вам:

```
  GetCursorPos(x); // текущее положение курсора
  Mouse.CursorPos:= Point({координата клика по оси х}, {координата клика по оси у});
  mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN...);  // значения сами поставите
  mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP...);
  // кликать по комбобоксу и отпускать кнопку надо будет раза 3, чтобы не текст выделялся, а курсор ставился
  // возвращаете курсор на месте
  Mouse.CursorPos:= x;
```

В моем случае координаты курсора для клика такие (как пример):

```
Point(self.Left + ComboBox1.Left + ComboBox1.Width - 12,
                          self.Top + ComboBox1.Top + 27);
```

Comment: самый крутой костыль из всех, что я когда-либо делал

Comment: Мне кажется логичнее не клики эмулировать, а непосредственно кареткой управлять, раз уж на то пошло )

Comment: @Nofate, в том то и дело, что это проще и логичнее! Но наш автор не из таких.

>> Вот решение под стать вам

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас есть **DBGrid** то соответственно есть и БД , а для БД логичней будет использовать **DBCombobox** , привязав его к нужному полю в базе, и вопрос с обновлением актуальных значений сам отпадет.

Comment: Не понял, почему отпадет. Под актуальными я имел в виду не те значения, которые сейчас в БД, а те, которые содержат введенные пользователем символы.

Comment: полная каша, с обсуждение сферического коня в вакууме. Дайте пример кода что ли вместе с куском БД.

Comment: товарищ пытается сделать поиск по базе, но делает это через (_о_).  Месьё знает толк в извращениях...

Answer (score 1):

Тут 2 вопроса:

1. Допускается ли свободный ввод, т.е. ввод данных которых нет в базе? В этом случае, ваш выпадающий список имеет функции обычного суфлера, и ответ в общем то дали.
2. Допускается вводить только те данные, которые есть в базе (это правило целостности и не противоречивости БД), в этом случае подвопросы – насколько много значений в выпадающем списке?
   Если много, то лучше их сгруппировать и, как уже предложили сначала выбирать группу, а потом уже из вашего списка.
   Если значений не много – можно грузить прямо в выпадающий список.
   Вопрос, что использовать **TDBLookupComboBox**, **TDBComboBox** или грузить в обычный **TComboBox** – дело религии, выбора оптимального функционала и удобства разработки.
   Как правило, если есть требование использовать только допустимые значения, то свойство **Style** выставляется в **csDropDownList**, тем самым, исключая возможность пользователя ввести что-то запрещенное, при этом, ввод значения возможен, но автоматически будет осуществляться поиск по всем Items по совпадению и подставляться пользователю (предлагаться).

Так что, надо определиться что использовать. Я предпочитаю обычный **TComboBox**. Это удобно.
В Strings (видимая часть Items) грузим «человеческие» названия а ключ (я надеюсь, у вас в БД есть понятия ключей и они как правило целочисленные..) грузим или в свойство Tag, но, не всегда удобно, например, если в роли ключа строковое значение или ключ не скалярный (например, несколько значений хотим сохранить для данной записи), то, делаем структуру (в терминах Pascal – record) и грузим в Data есть метод – у любого «комбобокса» - AddObject.
Как пример, рабочей процедуры:

Структура:

```
type

  PGroup = ^TGroup;
  TGroup = record
   Key:String;
   Name: String;
   id: Integer;
  end;
```

функция:

```
function Tdm.LoadListMat(list: TStrings; gr: String): integer;
var q:TOraQuery;
    p:PGroup;
begin
    q := TOraQuery.Create(nil);
    q.SQL.Text := 'SELECT MAT_KODE_KIS, MAT_NAME_KIS, GR_CODE FROM STOR.V_MATERIALS WHERE upper(gr_code) = upper(nvl(:gr,gr_code))';
    result := -1;
    try
       if length(gr) > 0 then
         q.ParamByName('gr').AsString := gr
       else
         q.ParamByName('gr').Clear;
       q.Active := true;
       q.First;
       list.Clear;
       while not q.Eof do
       begin
        new(p);
        p.Key := q.FieldByName('MAT_KODE_KIS').AsString;
        p.Name:= q.FieldByName('gr_code').AsString;
        list.AddObject(q.FieldValues['mat_name_kis'], TObject(p));
        q.Next;
       end;
       result := ord(list.Count > 0) -1;
    finally
     begin
      q.Active := false;
      q.Free;
     end;
    end;

end
```

;

а вот и вызов:

```
procedure TFAddMat.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    boxGroup.ItemIndex := dm.LoadGroupMat(boxGroup.Items);
    boxGroup.OnChange(boxGroup);
    boxMat.ItemIndex := dm.LoadListMat(boxMat.Items);
end;
```

где boxGroup и boxMat - TComboBox.
При этом, мы видим, что сначало грузятся группы, потом материалы...
на и, при изменении группы:

```
procedure TFAddMat.boxGroupChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
    LbGroup.Caption := PGroup(boxGroup.Items.Objects[boxGroup.ItemIndex]).Key;
    boxMat.ItemIndex := dm.LoadListMat(boxMat.Items,LbGroup.Caption );
end;
```

в LbGroup показывается текущая (выбранная) группа, и она же передаётся как параметр для заполнения списка.
функция LoadListMat имеет параметр по умолчанию..

```
function LoadListMat(list: TStrings; gr: String = ''): integer;
```

Comment: ТС реализует фильтр данных, возможно по нескольким полям, с autocomplete функцией. Данные в items комбобокса - это возможные строки, соответствующие каким-либо значениям или частям значения для фильтра. Дальше введенное или выбранное значение (в том числе не до конца введенное) подставляется в фильтр с like'ом.  
И проблема не в заполнении комбобокса или нескольких, а в поведении комбобокса при очистке Items - курсор в поле ввода скачет на начало строки. Если в onChange перезаполнять список Items и пытаться вводить "12345", то без ручного перемещения курсора будет "54321".

Comment: stells2, спасибо, но у меня немного другая история, как правильно заметил Yura Ivanov :)